# Calculate standard deviation over years in Stata

Tags: stata

I need to calculate the standard deviation of a company's sales over the last 3 years (from year t-2 until now) in Stata. My data has the following structure:
Firm.ID     SALES     YEAR

So each company comes back multiple times, with each year being a new line.

Comment: Can you show a sample of your data and expected output, and the code you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Consider this analogue using `rangestat` from SSC:

```
. webuse grunfeld, clear

. rangestat (count) invest (sd) invest, int(year -2 0) by(company)

. list year invest* if company == 1

     +--------------------------------------+
     | year   invest   invest~t   invest_sd |
     |--------------------------------------|
  1. | 1935    317.6          1           . |
  2. | 1936    391.8          2    52.46731 |
  3. | 1937    410.6          3   49.173296 |
  4. | 1938    257.7          3   83.381305 |
  5. | 1939    330.8          3   76.474459 |
     |--------------------------------------|
  6. | 1940    461.2          3   103.08574 |
  7. | 1941      512          3   93.468577 |
  8. | 1942      448          3   33.790726 |
  9. | 1943    499.6          3   33.941912 |
 10. | 1944    547.5          3   49.761464 |
     |--------------------------------------|
 11. | 1945    561.2          3   32.343625 |
 12. | 1946    688.1          3   77.523807 |
 13. | 1947    568.9          3   71.147171 |
 14. | 1948    529.2          3   82.698164 |
 15. | 1949    555.1          3   20.154985 |
     |--------------------------------------|
 16. | 1950    642.9          3   59.592155 |
 17. | 1951    755.9          3   100.66322 |
 18. | 1952    891.2          3   124.31678 |
 19. | 1953   1304.4          3   285.74248 |
 20. | 1954   1486.7          3   305.11956 |
     +--------------------------------------+
```